# Replace one backslash with two backslashes using sed

Tags: linux, sed

I am trying to replace '' with '\' character using sed command

```
echo "F:\RDAR\P003\P003\20220701" | sed 's/ \ / \\ /g'
```

I don't know what's wrong with this command

I expect this `'F:\\RDAR\\P003\\P003\\20220704'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the backslashes, so `\` becomes `\\`:

```
sed 's,\\,\\\\,g'
```

or the slightly more hard to read for people with eyesight like my own:

```
sed 's/\\/\\\\/g'
```